# Streaming mp4a to localhost using udp and ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, codec, mp4a

I am using the following command to stream a video and it's audio to localhost:
ffmpeg -re -i out.mp4 -map 0:0 -vcodec libx264 -f h264 udp://127.0.0.1:1234 -map 0:1 -acodec libfaac -f mp4a udp://127.0.0.1:2020

FFmpeg is not recognising my audio codec and my audio format so I get the following error message:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdcrD.png)

What audio format and codec do I need to use? The codec information of the video I wish to send is as follows:
[Codecs used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIDlc.png)

When I convert the audio track to mp3 I can run the above command and stream the video and audio properly. However I dont want to convert all my video audio-tracks to mp3.

(I am confused by all the encoders, decoders, codec names in the ffmpeg documentation) Is there a way of finding the right encoder to use with the mp4a audio codec other than reading the whole list of codecs and options?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need separate audio/video? If not you can simply stream them as `MPEG-TS` (`-f mpegts`) on a single port.

Comment: `mp4a` is not a valid format name; it's `mp4`. In any case, regular `mp4` can't be created over a network by ffmpeg. `mpegts`, as suggested, should work.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, mpegts was the right format, works well